# How to disable onclick if code have attribute disabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to create something like this:

If this code have attribute `disabled="disabled"`, my onclick is also disable

```
<a type="submit" disabled="disabled" id="my-form" onclick="javascript:yourFunctionName();" name="continue" data-target="#dialog" href=""
                class="btn primary btn-primary" title="End">End</a>
```

Comment: It is not valid HTML. `<a>` elements can't have `disabled` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

try this code, it will search for the  tag and if disabled="disabled" found it will remove the onclick attribute

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").each(function(){
      if($(this).attr("disabled") == "disabled") {
        $(this).attr("onclick","");
      }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to add a `class` named `disabled` to the `<a>` tag like below:

```
<a type="submit" id="my-form" onclick="javascript:yourFunctionName(this);" name="continue" data-target="#dialog" href=""

class="btn primary btn-primary disabled" title="End">End</a>
```

Then you can do like this in your `yourFunctionName()` :

```
function yourFunctionName(id) {
   event.preventDefault();
   if(id.className.indexOf('disabled'))
   {
      alert('Sorry, link is disabled');
      return false;
   }
   //Function Code goes here    
 }
```